# How do I determine when a user will turn 18 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am having trouble with task 9:

```js
// Task #7) Prompt the user for their birthday and convert it to a Date object
    
//   Remember - when prompting the user, it comes in as a string
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var birthDate = prompt("Enter your birthdate mm/dd/yyyy");
var bd = new Date(birthDate);

// Task #8) Display the date the user was born in a format that shows the day of the week, month, date, and year
document.write("You were born on " + days[bd.getDay()] + ", ");
document.write(months[bd.getMonth()] + " ");
document.write(bd.getDate() + ", " + bd.getFullYear() + "<br>");

// Task #9) Calculate when the user turned 18

// Task #10) Display the 18th birthday in a format
//   that shows the day of the week, month, date, and year
```

Comment: Since you have the birthday, and the year, you can use date-fns to count the number of days to the 18th year birthday. A quick google on **date-fns** can get you to the right place. I'm recommending what's already available so you don't need to calculate leap years manually.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
const turn18 = new Date(db.getFullYear() + 18, db.getMonth(), db.getDate())
```

Comment: This is fine, as long as you would like a person who was born on Feb 29 to have their 18th birthday on March 1.  If you want them to have it on Feb 28, there is more work to do.